# Book for Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods

Tags: reference-request

Can anyone recommend a good book for MCMC? I have worked with HMMs, Markov Chains in the past but nothing on simulation. So something in the intermediate level would be great. Also, if you know of any introductory books on stochastic simulation, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a book on MCMC which covers a lot of topics:

Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo, edited by Brooks, Gelman, Jones, and Meng.

from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420079417)

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked in [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/good-sources-for-learning-markov-chain-monte-carlo-mcmc) there are more answers over there if you want to check them out!

Answer (score 0):

**"Statistical Mechanics"** by ***Werner Krauth*** is a good book. Covers MCMC well in its initial chapters. 
[http://blancopeck.net/Statistics.pdf][1]